# Как правильно наносить термопасту?

Tags: cpu

Процессор квадратный, медный сердечник радиатора круглый.
Пересмотрел несколько статей, наносят на процессор, покрывая его полностью.
Но сам интел не замазывали весь процессор, след от термопасты на нем был круглый (от радиатора).
Получается правильно мазать на медный сердечник радиатора?

Comment: Данный вопрос следует закрыть, потому что он не относится ни к программированию, ни к системному администрированию.

Answer (score 2):

Капать строго в центр (не размазывать)!.

Если предварительно размажите - гарантировано наличие микропузырей. А это очевидное падение теплопроводности.

Answer (score 0):

Как то натыкался на инструкцию, где было написано что термопасту необходимо капнуть в центре процессора, после когда ты будешь ставить радиатор, она должна растечься. Но в практике, смотришь какое у тебя пятно соприкосновения, обычно это вся площадь процессора, и размазываешь термопасту немного не доходя до краев, чтобы когда поставишь радиатор, ее не выдавило.